# Devise routing error ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PUT] "/"):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

After make a PUT api call in /dashboard_users/update, devise return me a error message:

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PUT] "/")

Here is the full error:

```
Started PUT "/dashboard_users" for ::1 at 2019-10-15 13:34:12 +0700
13:34:12 web.1    |    (0.6ms)  SET NAMES utf8,  @@SESSION.sql_mode = CONCAT(CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',STRICT_ALL_TABLES'), ',NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'),  @@SESSION.sql_auto_is_null = 0, @@SESSION.wait_timeout = 2147483
13:34:12 web.1    |   ↳ /home/theo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
13:34:12 web.1    | Processing by RegistrationsController#update as HTML
13:34:12 web.1    |   Parameters: {"dashboard_user"=>{"last_name"=>"Cerutti", "first_name"=>"Théo"}, "registration"=>{"dashboard_user"=>{"last_name"=>"Cerutti", "first_name"=>"Théo"}}}
13:34:12 web.1    |   DashboardUser Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  `dashboard_users`.* FROM `dashboard_users` WHERE `dashboard_users`.`id` = 1 ORDER BY `dashboard_users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
13:34:12 web.1    |   ↳ /home/theo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
13:34:12 web.1    | get_vendor succeeded on /get_vendor
13:34:12 web.1    |   DashboardUser Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `dashboard_users`.* FROM `dashboard_users` WHERE `dashboard_users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
13:34:12 web.1    |   ↳ /home/theo/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
13:34:12 web.1    |    (0.1ms)  BEGIN
13:34:12 web.1    |   ↳ app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:26
13:34:12 web.1    |    (0.2ms)  COMMIT
13:34:12 web.1    |   ↳ app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:26
13:34:12 web.1    | Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
13:34:12 web.1    | Completed 302 Found in 62ms (ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)
13:34:12 web.1    | 
13:34:12 web.1    | 
13:34:12 web.1    | Started PUT "/" for ::1 at 2019-10-15 13:34:12 +0700
13:34:12 web.1    |   
13:34:12 web.1    | ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PUT] "/"):
13:34:12 web.1    |   
13:34:12 web.1    | actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:65:in `call'
13:34:12 web.1    | web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
13:34:12 web.1    | web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:30:in `block in call'
13:34:12 web.1    | web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `catch'
13:34:12 web.1    | web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `call'
13:34:12 web.1    | actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
13:34:12 web.1    | railties (5.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
13:34:12 web.1    | railties (5.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
13:34:12 web.1    | activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
13:34:12 web.1    | activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
13:34:12 web.1    | activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
13:34:12 web.1    | railties (5.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
13:34:12 web.1    | sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
13:34:12 web.1    | actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
13:34:12 web.1    | actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
13:34:12 web.1    | rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
13:34:12 web.1    | rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
13:34:12 web.1    | activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
13:34:12 web.1    | actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
13:34:12 web.1    | actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
13:34:12 web.1    | rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
13:34:12 web.1    | webpacker (4.0.7) lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:29:in `perform_request'
13:34:12 web.1    | rack-proxy (0.6.5) lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
13:34:12 web.1    | railties (5.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
13:34:12 web.1    | puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'
13:34:12 web.1    | puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/server.rb:660:in `handle_request'
13:34:12 web.1    | puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/server.rb:474:in `process_client'
13:34:12 web.1    | puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/server.rb:334:in `block in run'
13:34:12 web.1    | puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

My api call work because it updates my user.
I think the response format causes this error..

EDIT: client side:

```
  axios.put('http://localhost:3000/dashboard_users', data).then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

EDIT: find a weird thing

I created a RegistrationsController (herited by devise controller):

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  respond_to :json

  protected

  # override update_resource for updating user without password if no password passed
  # else if password is given password will be updated
  def update_resource(resource, params)
    # Require current password if user is trying to change password.
    return super if params['password']&.present?

    # Allows user to update registration information without password.
    resource.update_without_password(params.except('current_password'))
  end
end
```

my route:

```
`devise_for :dashboard_users, controllers: { registrations: 'registrations' }, defaults: { format: 'json' }`
```

If I put default: { format: 'json' } in my route and respond_to :json in my controller my api call doesn't make any error !

BUT my other route which are rendered with a view (example sign_in) make a UnknownFormatError when trying to accessing to it.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you hit the API twice with different requests. Can you share the client source code please?

Comment: i edited my aswner, tell me if you want more code

Comment: The application is redirected to `/` path with the put method after update. That's why you get an error. Check your update action.

Comment: It's the devise action.. I find something weird, I edited my post

Comment: @TheoCerutti remove `respond_to :json` from `RegistrationsController ` and try it again.

Comment: if i put respond_to :json -> error of PUT "/",    if i put default json in route -> can't access to sign_in route (rendered by a view), if i put default json and respond_to :json -> can't access to sign_in route (rendered by a view), i don't put both -> PUT "/" error

Comment: Ok ok, I think I understand, when I try to update, sign_in, sign_up devise redirect_me to my root link ('/') even if I make an api call. So if I want to resolve this issue I need to tell to devise that if i make an api call then don't redirect me, but how can i do that ?